I need to remove a blank line which is produced in the output file(s) from this batch script
I was given this script to use, which creates multiple copies of the same file, all named from a list. It works perfectly other than an extra blank line being created after the word clank.
I need the files to contain only the word clank on its own line, with no additional spaces or blank lines.
With hundreds of files to create, I can't feasibly manually edit each file to remove the blank line after the fact.
@ECHO ON
::: Implicit
:::: Ensure there are NO SPACES in this path
SET FileList=List.txt
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN (%FileList%) DO (
    ECHO. >>"%%~F.mat"
    CALL :CreateFile "%%~F.mat"
)
GOTO EOF
:CreateFile
ECHO ^clank>"%~1"
GOTO EOF

Here's a couple of images.
What the current file looks like upon creation:

What it should look like:

Everything I try is to no avail.

All Windows files end their lines with a carriage return and line feed pair, 0x0D0x0A. The 'blank line' is therefore a harmless and realistic expectation. If you want to have Unix style line endings, i.e. line feed only, you should change evey line, not just the final one.

First you should improve your code. Change ::: Implicit to Rem Implicit, remove :::: Ensure there are NO SPACES in this path, change SET FileList=List.txt to Set "FileList=List.txt", change FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN (%FileList%) DO (, to For /F "UseBackQ EOL=? Delims=" %%F In ("%FileList%") Do (. Now you can finally remove ECHO. >>"%%~F.mat", and change ECHO ^clank>"%~1" to Set /P "=clank" 0<NUL 1>"%~1", to fix your reported problem.

I omitted to mention in my previous comment, that you obviously need to change @ECHO ON to @Echo Off too. Please choose something different for viewing or modifying files with line feed only endings. Windows notepad.exe has never traditionally been a good choice for doing so.

@Compo thanks for this, it's worked perfectly. I very much appreciate your help!

That is not a blank line in your first image.  There is physically not a single character on the line below clank. As already said in a previous comment by Compo the line endings on a line will tell the Program you are using to go to the end of the file if you tell it it to using whatever combination of keyboard characters.  If you use any scripting language or utility like wc to count the number of lines in the file it will tell you 1 every single time.
